# SharePoint Search how create Crawled property

Tags: sharepoint-search

Is any way to force create crawled properties using PowerShell for site collumns without having any content in this fields ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible (at least using on-prem version of SharePoint).

Using a PowerShell admin console, you can use [`New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spenterprisesearchmetadatacrawledproperty?view=sharepoint-ps):

```
New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -Name $crawledProperty.Name `
                                              -Category $crawledProperty.CategoryName `
                                              -VariantType $crawledProperty.VariantType `
                                              -PropSet $crawledProperty.PropSet `
                                              -IsMappedToContents $crawledProperty.IsMappedToContents `
                                              -IsNameEnum $false `
                                              -SearchApplication $SearchApplication
```

Some arguments aren't obvious. In order to help find this values, I suggest you to export an existing one (in a design site collection for example):

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty | ? { $_.Name -match "ows_YourField" }
```

You can even build more complex scripts that exports crawled properties, managed properties and mappings regarding a field name prefix (a good practice!) into a cv file or similar, then reimport them at the target.